# Firestore, rules-unit-testing with/without @firebase/firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, testing, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I am genuinly confused by the [rule testing docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator#:%7E:text=//%20Assuming%20a%20Firestore%20app%20and%20the%20Firestore%20emulator) at this point.

They are assuming an emulator, does that mean it's possible without one?

Why are they importing `@firebase/firestore` if the tests don't rlly need it since the refs gained by using the `RulesContext` have the `admin-sdk` dot-notation style.

Here 2 examples

```js
// Setup
const authedSetsRef =  testEnv.authenticatedContext(id).firestore().collection(name)

// With only rules-unit-testing package
assertFails(authedSetsRef.get())

// Their docs
assertFails(getDocs(authedSetsRef)) // <= Why this way with the extra import
```

More complicated confusing example why I even came to this issue, the OR queries.
I do not find an option to do these with the `rules-unit-testing` package.

- With `@firebase/firestore`
- With `@admin-sdk`

[Link to those 2 examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries), the 1st is under `web modular api` the 2nd under dropdown>node.js (where the admin sdk always is)

But neither option is usable in the rules-unit-testing package........??????
atleast there is no Filer.or to import

Comment: "*They are assuming an emulator, does that mean it's possible without one?*" - that's certainly what the documentation suggests, since it's part of the instructions, without alternative. The emulator provides the logic that evaluates the rules, both for testing and local development.

Comment: If you have a feature request for the rules-unit-testing package, why don't you file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) about that? Stack Overflow probably won't have a solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are they importing @firebase/firestore if the tests don't [really] need it since the refs gained by using the RulesContext have the `admin-sdk` dot-notation style.

The `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` package is currently built around the `firebase/compat/*` compatibility libraries that emulate the legacy namespaced SDK's syntax (what you refer to as `admin-sdk` dot-notation). This was likely done so that updating tests could be done progressively as users [upgraded their projects to the modular syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Because the library imports these legacy versions of the code, you can use either syntax if you are continuing an old project, but for new projects you should follow the [modular SDK testing methods documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator#run_local_unit_tests).

> ... the OR queries. I do not find an option to do these with the rules-unit-testing package.

You will need to import `or()` from the "firebase/firestore" library. It is a new feature that is unsupported by the legacy namespaced syntax.

The below examples use this import block:

```
import {
  assertFails,
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeTestEnvironment
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing"

import {
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  or,
  query,
  where
} from "firebase/firestore";
```

Setting up the test environment:

```
let testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
  projectId: "demo-project-1234",
  firestore: {
    rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
  },
});

const USERID_UNDER_TEST = "user-abc";
const userAuthedTestEnv = testEnv.authenticatedContext(USERID_UNDER_TEST);
const db = userAuthedTestEnv.firestore();
```

Actioning a test for data of all users:

```
const usersColRef = collection(db, "users");

// returns a promise, chain appropriately
assertFails(getDocs(usersColRef));
```

Actioning a test for the user's own data:

```
const usersColRef = collection(db, "users");
const userDocRef = doc(usersColRef, USERID_UNDER_TEST);

// returns a promise, chain appropriately
assertSucceeds(getDoc(userDocRef));
```

Actioning a test for finding important messages that user is the recipient of, where each message is unread or mentions the user by their username:

```
const messagesColRef = collection(db, "messages");
const importantMessagesQuery = query(
  messagesColRef,
  where("recipient", "==", USERID_UNDER_TEST),
  or(
    where("read", "==", false),
    where("mentionedRecipient", "==", true)
  )
)

// returns a promise, chain appropriately
assertSucceeds(getDocs(importantMessagesQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains a lot, i guess it was unfortunate that I never came across the information of it being legacy code :/ too bad I changed everything to the legacy version haha

Comment: I feel that the `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` and its documentation doesn't get as much love as it should have.